# Automation WorkTask

Tags: sql, automation, task

need your idea guys how to develop Automation WorkTask.
Actually, i want to create a automation WorkTask by pulling the data from SQL. I always used a website : XXX to submit Work Task. In another hand, i need to pull the data from SQL. SO, i will used the data from SQL and manually insert to the website to submit Work Task. my idea is, i want to make it as one. meaning that, whenever, i pull the data, it will automatically, send the data to the website and auto submit Work Task. can anyone help me to do that? or it is impossible? - Noobiest SQL

Answer (score 0):

Use a Console Application. From there you can extract the data, format it in any way you want and even automate the upload of that information using the .NET library.

Then with the windows scheduler, you can tell it to run however often you need to.

For example, I have an application that runs every 5 minutes, reads a database, gets the info, then executes a number of tasks using it. It's scheduled to run every 5 minutes.